# Append an array using express, Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to the MERN stack and I am trying to create users that have an empty queue, which will hold telephone numbers in E.164 format. I aim to populate and remove these numbers from the queue (type: Array) depending on API calls.

The issue is, I am able to update the array, but it overwrites every time the call is made, but I want it to append instead.

The part that I believe I need to amend is `user.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{ '$set' : { queue : req.body.number}}` but I am unable to find the way to get it to append instead of update.

I know using `.push()` will append an array, but how do I implement that within my controller?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**userController.js**

```
var router = express.Router()

var ObjectID = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId


var { user } = require('../models/user')

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    user.find((err,docs) => {
        (!err) ? res.send(docs) : console.error('Error whilst getting documents : ' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
        
    })
})

router.post('/new',(req,res) => {
    var newRecord = new user ({
        name : req.body.name,
        company : req.body.company,
        email : req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        queue : []
        
    })

    newRecord.save((err,docs) => {
        (!err) ? res.send(docs) : console.error('Error whilst creating new user : ' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
    })
})

router.put('/addToQueue/:id', (req, res) => {
    if(!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send("No record exists with given id : " + req.params.id)
  
    
    user.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{ '$set' : { queue : req.body.number}},(err,docs) => {
        (!err) ? res.send(docs) : console.error('Error updating queue : ' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
    })
})


module.exports = router
```

**POSTMAN**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$push` for that.

Try this:

```
user.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { '$push': { 'queue': req.body.number } }, (err, docs) => {
    (!err) ? res.send(docs) : console.error('Error updating queue : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
})
```

Comment: thank you very much, thought it was something so simple.